# Can't understand which subpackage for JModel is for 2.5x

Tags: joomla

I can't find a real subpackage for an abstract class JModel (platform 12.1: http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Platform/Application/JModel.html). 
There is pointed:

```
Class JObject   (Subpackage Base)
   Abstract class JModel   (Subpackage Application)
```

I don't see it in a packages tree. I don't see `Base->JObject`, nor `Application->JModel`, nor `Object -> JObject -> JModel`.  I literally have no any idea where it can be found...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2.5 you should use  the  JLegacyModel class which Valentin mentioned. The base JModel class is in the legacy folder while the subclasses are in the cms folder.  This will let you switch to J3 when you want.

libraries/legacy/model/model.php

Answer (score 1):

You can extend JModel in your class, as well as JModelList, JModelItem, JModelForm etc.

It really depends on what you want to do.

The actual implementation can be found under:

```
libraries/joomla/application/component/model.php or modeladmin.php etc.
```

Comment: I know it. The question was - which subpackage contains abstract class JModel? Where within a packages tree may I find it out?